# Unable to load EJB module

Tags: java, glassfish

I am taking a course in Enterprise Application Development.  I am new to JSF.  I am trying to deploy my app using  Glassfish 3.1 using JSF and Netbeans IDE.

The error I get is listed below.

`Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for F:\Seagate\docs backup\NetBeansProjects\ent-app-dev\Slamka_Project1\build\web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected. Please see server.log for more details.`

Below are the references to EJB I have made.

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
@EJB
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  This is a Java Web Application.

**EDIT**
WAR FILE STRUCTURE TREE

- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF/classes
- WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-2.1.1.jar
- WEB-INF/web.xml
- index.shtml

My file does not have an EJB tag in teh xhtml document.  it has what is listed below.

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">`

Comment: Post more code and jar structure

Comment: Can't seem to get the directory structure into a list format.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the *web.xml* `web-app` attribute version to `2.5` or higher resolved this issue.

Updated web-app element of *web.xml* will be,

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have web application, it's not ejb-jar, it's web module that sould be packeged to `*.war` archive.
Structure should be

- *.war/META-INF/persistence.xml
- *.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- *.war/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml
- *.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
- *.war/WEB-INF/classes/ - compiled classes in packages
- *.war/WEB-INF/lib/ - libs
- *.war/index.jsp - home page

example of `sun-web.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
  <context-root>/app</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

if you are using `Maven`, you can use `maven-war-plugin`

Comment: I tried replacing the html with ejb-jar and that did not work.  Probably not doing it right though.

Comment: I am using Facelets and GlassFish.  I know I am not using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was a typo in a SQL statement (1 and l [lower case L]) and I needed to do a "Clean and build" on the project.  Thank you for those who put effort into helping me solve my issue.